# getting error in $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have create a web API in C# and call that api from jquery but getting error:

```
('#buttonid').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
     method: "GET",url: "http://localhost:54580/api/persons",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
      beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate");
            },
       async: true,
     success: function (data) {

     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    },
      error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
           if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
                 console.log(jqXHR.responseText); 
           }else{
                console.log("Something went wrong");
           }
      }
}); 
});
```

in debug mode I am able to see my data.:

```
http://localhost:54580/api/persons?callback=jQuery111103874004708615564_1461475734608&_=1461475734609
```

The data is:

```
[{
    "FirstName": "Ramu",
    "LastName": "Rai",
    "Email": "test123"
}, {
    "FirstName": "Ramu1",
    "LastName": "Rai1",
    "Email": "test123"
}]
```

but code never goes in success section. it always print "Something went wrong"

Comment: What is the `errorThrown` given when "Something went wrong" is logged?

Comment: I am printing errorThrown in console.log() and it prints: Something went wrongError: jQuery111105166638258522127_1461476377224 was not called

Answer (score 0):

Use `json` instead of `jsonp`, try demo below (replace url)

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", //"http://localhost:54580/api/persons",
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate");
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var result = JSON.stringify(data);
    var $result = document.querySelector('#pre');
    $result.textContent = result;
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
    if (jqXHR.status && jqXHR.status == 400) {
      console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log("Something went wrong");
    }
  }
});
function my_function(data){
  console.log('my_function', data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: yes I am able to run this.I am getting result but what i wrong in my example.Is it something wrong on web service side.

Comment: Your server is not configured to use jsonp

Comment: could you please tell me how I can do this. my server is returning JSON.[{"FirstName":"Ramu","LastName":"Rai","Email":"test123"},{"FirstName":"Ramu1","LastName":"Rai1","Email":"test123"}]

Comment: To use jsonp, your server must return data with Content-type: application/javascript. But your server returns application/json

Comment: still I haven't resolve this. I have written rest service in JAX RS. below is the code:                                                                                                                      @Path("/person")

public class PersonInfo {
 
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<Person> getPersons()
 {
  List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<Person>();
  
  persons.add(new Person("ram","rai","test123"));
  persons.add(new Person("raju","rai","test123"));
  return persons;

 }

}

Comment: if you see I have mentioned mediaType: Application_JSON and able to see  content in postman

Comment: Read my previous comment carefully